Add grpc interceptor with numeric parameter in construcotr using factory in ASP .NET Core
I can register a grpc client in DI containter and add an interceptor usin the following code.
builder.Services.AddSingleton<MyInterceptor>();

builder.Services
    .AddGrpcClient<MyService.MyServiceClient>()
    .AddInterceptor<MyInterceptor>();

However, the above solution doesn't work if there is a parameter in MyInterceptor's constructor:
public sealed class MyInterceptor : Interceptor
{
    private readonly int _parameter;

    public MyInterceptor (int parameter)
    {
        _parameter = parameter;
    }
    // more stuff here
}

No I have to use less elegant way of interceptor registration:
builder.Services
        .AddGrpcClient<MyService.MyServiceClient>()
        .AddInterceptor(() => new MyInterceptor(1));

which doesn't seem very nice to me. Also this solution is not very optimal when I need many interceptors with the same parameter value as it leads to unneccessary memory consumption.
Thus, I decided to use a factory pattern to reuse interceptors with the same parameter value.
public class MyInterceptorPool
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, MyInterceptor> _pool;

    public MyInterceptorPool()
    {
        _pool = [];
    }

    public MyInterceptor GetOrAddMyInterceptor(int parameter)
    {
        if (_pool.TryGetValue(parameter, out var value))
            return value;

        value = new MyInterceptor(parameter);
        _pool.Add(parameter, value);

        return value;
    }
}

Now I can register my factory as a Singleton and use it to add interceptors like so:
var interceptorPool = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<GrpcDeadlineInterceptorPool>();

builder.Services
            .AddGrpcClient<MyService.MyServiceClient>()
            .AddInterceptor(() => interceptorPool.GetOrAddDeadlineInterceptor(10));

or alternatively
builder.Services
            .AddGrpcClient<MyService.MyServiceClient>()
            .AddInterceptor(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<MyInterceptorPool>().GetOrAddDeadlineInterceptor(10));

While this approach solves the issue, i wonder if there's a more elegant solution? Perhaps using keyed service registration?
Additionally, I'm uncertain whether using aDictionary in MyInterceptorPool is appropriate? Perhaps I should go with ConcurrentDictionary if ASP .NET Core has some multithreading application configuration.
Any thoughts and comments are highly appreciated.

The default dependency injection container in .NET doesn't have good support for  injecting an int as a constructor parameter. One option is to create a new class that handles your configuration and inject that instead. For example:
public class InterceptorConfig
{
   // Leaving it up to you to decide how you get this value
   public int Parameter { get; set; } 
}

Now add this class to your DI container:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<InterceptorConfig>();

builder.Services
    .AddGrpcClient<MyService.MyServiceClient>()
    .AddInterceptor<MyInterceptor>();

And consume it in your interceptor class:
public sealed class MyInterceptor : Interceptor
{
    private readonly int _parameter;

    public MyInterceptor (InterceptorConfig interceptorConfig)
    {
        // Get the parameter here, or store the config if you want to use it later
        _parameter = interceptorConfig.Parameter;
    }
    // more stuff here
}


Thanks for your reply. I can't go straight with the code you provided because I can add more grpc clients and set different parameter value for them. So this singleton config won't work :(

Then change the config class to give you different values, for example a function that returns a value based on a key. Plenty of options.

Consider having 3 clients MyClient1, MyClient2 and MyClient3. I want to add MyInterceptor(1) to MyClient1, MyInterceptor(2) to MyClient2 and MyInterceptor(3) to MyClient3. Can you provide an example, please? Can't figure it out myself...

Perhaps the required parameter should also be added to the DI in the options. And then, in the interceptor, receive this parameter from the DI.
For example, services from DI can be obtained like this:
    var validator = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IValidator<TRequest>>();

Do the same with options
